# golang 1.6 cross compile

Tags: go, cross-compiling

In golang 1.6, when I cross compile from my 64-bit arch to 32-bit for Linux, the `go install` command puts the executable in `bin/linux_386/<exe>`.

Is there a way to put it into `bin/` instead?  If I build in the 32-bit environment, then it will go in `bin/`.  I want the exe to go into the same location regardless of if I cross compile to 32-bit outside the sandbox, or natively compile inside the 32-bit sandbox.

My workaround right now is to soft link the `linux_386` dir to `.`, as in `ln -s . linux_386`.

Comment: Go is trying to avoid putting incompatible binaries in your PATH. What's wrong with having it in the bin/linux_386 directory?

Comment: I have two ways to build the executable.  One inside the 32 bit sandbox uses the 32 bit version of go.  One outside the sandbox uses the 64 bit version of go that cross compiles.  I want both to put the executable in the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with go install, however you can do it manually:

```
 go build -o $GOPATH/bin/<exe> $GOPATH/src/your/<pkg>
```

Comment: Also adding the `-i` option will install out of date dependencies, basically giving you the behavior of `go install`